# How to create a div with the size of a specific div

Tags: jquery, height, width

How to create a div with the size (height and width in css) of a specific div.

```
$('<div/>').css({
    "display" : "block";
    "width" : width();
    "height" : height();
}).appendTo('#fixed');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the outerHeight()/outerWidth() properties.  This will include any margin and padding applied to the target element:

```
$('<div/>').css({
    "display" : "block",
    "width" : $('#myelem').outerWidth(),
    "height" : $('#myelem').outerHeight()
}).appendTo('#fixed');
```

Pay attention to the formatting in my parameter element.  Javascript object props are separated by commas

Comment: You should add +'px' otherwise old browsers will not appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it:

```
var $target = $('#fixed');
$('<div/>').css({
    "width" : $target.innerWidth(),
    "height" : $target.innerHeight();
}).appendTo($target);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
$('<div/>').css({
    "display" : "block";
    "width" : $('#divTarget').outerWidth()+'px';
    "height" : $('#divTarget').outerHeight()+'px';
}).appendTo('#fixed');
```